# How to see which Rust features are enabled for a dependency

Tags: rust

When compiling, I would like to see which specific features were enabled for a given dependency. Is there a flag/setting to see that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best one, but you can use [`cargo tree`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-tree.html) to do this.

For dependency `serde`:

```
cargo tree --edges features --depth 1 --invert serde
```

```
serde v1.0.193
└── serde_json v1.0.108
├── serde feature "default"
├── serde feature "derive"
├── serde feature "serde_derive"
└── serde feature "std"
```

This also prints crates that depend on the selected crate, but you can filter those out.